# Local Image Base64 conversion error Javascript

Tags: html, css, websocket, socket.io

After the code and the errors at the bottom I have added a question for the code.

```
/Connect user to new socket
var socket = io.connect(“http://localhost:3000“);

//Waits till dom is loaded before initializing variables
document.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”, function()
{
    var btn = document.getElementById(“submit”);
    var food = document.getElementById(“food”);
    var location = document.getElementById(“location”);
    var deal = document.getElementById(“deal”);
    var img = document.getElementById(“file”).files[0];


   btn.addEventListener(“click”, function()
    {

   var x = getBase64(img);

   var foodItem =
    {
        name: food.value,
        location: location.value,
        deal: deal.value,
        votes: 0,
        image: x
    };

       socket.emit(“addFood”, foodItem)


   });
});

   document.getElementById(“submit”).addEventListener(“click”, function() {

   //window.location.href = “confirmPage.html”;
    });



   function getBase64(img) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file) {
        console.log(5)
        console.log(reader.readAsDataURL);
        reader.addEventListener(“load”, function() {
        console.log(5)
        return reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    })
    }
    console.log(5)

 }


[1:01] 
html :


[1:02] 
<html lang=“en”>
    <head>
        <link href=“css/createDeal.css” type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet”>              
       <script  src=“https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js“></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Food: <input type=“text” id=“food”><br>
        Location: <input type=“text” id=“location”><br>
        Deal: <input type=“text” id=“deal”><br>
        Image: <input type=“file” id=“file”>
        <button id=“submit”>Submit</button>
        <script src=“js/createDeal.js” type=“text/javascript”></script>
    </body>
</html>


[1:02] 
error:


[1:02] 
createDeal.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute ‘readAsDataURL’ on ‘FileReader’: parameter 1 is not of type ‘Blob’.
    at getBase64 (createDeal.js:51)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (createDeal.js:17)
getBase64 @ createDeal.js:51
(anonymous) @ createDeal.js:17
```

I am trying to have a user upload a local image using input filetype in html. I then want to take that image and then convert it into base64 and store string as an object and send it to the server. But I am getting the errors from readAsDataURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getBase64` function returns `undefined` since `readAsDataURL` doesn't have a return. It reads the file and then populates `result` on your reader.

I reworked the example code that MDN has on their page for [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) so you can see the difference.

There's an event and event listener here, `readAsDataURL` triggers the readers `load` event, and within the event handler we can grab the base64 result that's now attached.

Take note, there's still a `data:image/jpeg;base64,` prefix on the base64 string which you might have to remove depending on what's going to be consuming the string. `img` tags will take that string as-is as a `src` and be fine, but if you're storing the image on a file system and accessing it that way, the prefix might trip up some image viewers:

```js
function getBase64() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img.base64');
  var textPreview= document.querySelector('div.base64');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
    textPreview.textContent = reader.result;
    console.log("reader.result", reader.result);
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="getBase64()"><br>
<img height="200" alt="image preview..." src="" class="base64" />
<div>base64:</div>
<div class="base64"></div>
```